# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Python 3 Read Write Data

Tags: python, dynamics-crm

I'm working with an older on premise installation of Dynamics CRM 2013.

The customer needs some data to be read and written to the CRM from a separate application. I've figured out that I can read the data from '/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc' using python requests and authenticate with requests_ntlm2.

But how does writing data work is it even possible?

For the the reading part I've implemented simple requests function, but for writing I've mostly only been searching around StackOverFlow and other forums. I need to be a bit careful because I'm also working on live data so I don't want to just post data and break something.

Comment: separate application can be in C#? in that way you can use an older SDK and it's way simpler than using the OData 2.0 endpoint or the SOAP endpoint

Comment: Sadly no. The separate application is a actually an already existing web app made with python and some new features are being added. The customer is migrating to dynamics 365 but that is long way away from being done and needs new functionality now.